# Java Spring Boot Connecting Mobile-ID for authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-binding

I trying to use Mobile ID: https://github.com/SK-EID/mid-rest-java-demo . Technically I copied all services, models, exceptions and configs from there and pasted it to my code, but instead of using `ModelAndView`, I use `ResponseEntity` as method returning type. By some reason it drops following error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap["org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userRequest"]->org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult["messageCodesResolver"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at ee.refinance.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:35) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap["org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userRequest"]->org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult["messageCodesResolver"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:404) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:643) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1433) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:921) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 81 common frames omitted

2020-12-03 17:31:20.180  WARN 11924 --- [nio-8220-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap["org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userRequest"]->org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult["messageCodesResolver"])]
```

When I'm trying to call this method:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/authenticationRequest")
  public ResponseEntity sendAuthenticationRequest(@ModelAttribute("userRequest") @Valid UserRequest userRequest,
                                                  BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      System.out.println("Input validation error");
      return new ResponseEntity(userRequest, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    AuthenticationSessionInfo authenticationSessionInfo = authenticationService.startAuthentication(userRequest);
    userMidSession.setAuthenticationSessionInfo(authenticationSessionInfo);

    model.addAttribute("verificationCode", authenticationSessionInfo.getVerificationCode());

    return new ResponseEntity(model, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

UserRequest as well:

```
public class UserRequest {

  private String phoneNumber;

  @NotNull
  @Pattern(regexp="[0-9]{11}",
    message="Invalid national identity number")
  private String nationalIdentityNumber;

  @NotNull
  @Pattern(regexp="\\+37[0-9]{5,10}",
    message="Invalid phone number")
  public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
  }

  private MultipartFile file;

  public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  }

  public String getNationalIdentityNumber() {
    return nationalIdentityNumber;
  }

  public void setNationalIdentityNumber(String nationalIdentityNumber) {
    this.nationalIdentityNumber = nationalIdentityNumber;
  }

  public MultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
  }

  public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

What can be done to solve such error?